# FullCalendar won't bind to Json feed from ASP.NET MVC3 Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I am failing to get the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jquery plugin to bind to a Json array coming from an ASP.NET MVC3 action.

I have removed almost everything from the code to try to hunt down the problem; I'm left with this, which from every SO and blog post I've read, ought to work:

**Action (Calendar controller)**

```
    public JsonResult Events(double start, double end)
    {
        var rows = new object[] { new { title="Event1", start= "2011-04-04" }, 
                                  new { title="Event2", start= "2011-04-05" } };
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

**View**

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: '@Url.Content("~/Calendar/Events")'
     })
});
```

The results are a blank calendar, with no bound events. I have verified that the Json is being retrieved:

**Json result**

```
[{"title":"Event1","start":"2011-04-04"},{"title":"Event2","start":"2011-04-05"}]
```

And this works fine:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           events: [{title: 'Event1',start: '2011-04-04'},
                    {title: 'Event2',start: '2011-04-05'}
                   ]});
   });
```

I have tried using all number of date formats (including ISO8601 and *nix timestamps and gotten the same result: no bound events, just a blank calendar. If I add an $.ajax error: function to the .fullCalendar object, it fires, so presumably something's up with the Json being returned -- but it looks fine to me.

I'm using FullCalendar 1.5 (though I also tried 1.4.11), JQuery 1.5.1, JQueryUI 1.8.11.

I've tried everything I can think of -- any ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: I stepped through and found the issue -- there's a function name collision with jquery.validate.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stepped through and found the issue -- there's a function name collision between fullcalendar.js and jquery.validate.js.

Comment: which function? Could you provide more details please.

Comment: No, I don't remember; this was 30 months ago. If it's critical, you could run some old versions? But the problem was solved by the later versions, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of this:

```
return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Try This:

```
return Json(rows.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or instead of this:

```
events: '@Url.Content("~/Calendar/Events")'
```

Try this:

```
events: '@Url.Action("Events", "Calendar")'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the JSON is being returned correctly, so changing the way UrlHelper builds the URL doesn't make a difference. And my rows parameter already is an array.  The problem is definitely jquery.validate.js.

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajax() method.

**Action (Calendar controller)**

```
    public JsonResult Events(string start, string end)
    {
        //convert string to date
        DateTime _start = DateTime.TryParse(start, out _start) ? _start : DateTime.Now.Date; 
        DateTime _end = DateTime.TryParse(end, out _end) ? _end : DateTime.Now.Date; 

        var rows =
        new object[] { new { title="Event1", start= "2011-04-04" },                                    
        new { title="Event2", start= "2011-04-05" } };
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: function (start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Calendar/Events")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.toLocaleString("yyyy-mm-dd"),
                end: end.toLocaleString("yyyy-mm-dd")
            },  

            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                $.each(doc, function (key, val) {
                    events.push({
                        title: val.title,
                        start: val.start, 
                        url: 'http://google.com'
                    });
                });  

                callback(events); 
            }  
        });  
    }  
    });  
    })
```

Hopes this will help.

Comment: Nope, the problem was definitely the name collision we discovered last year. Expanding the ajax call wouldn't help -- but using a more recent version of jquery.validate.js did.

Comment: Heh. I was having a similar problem. Except the tutorial I had followed specified start and end as double, not as strings. I noticed that in your code they were strings and I gave it a shot.

Turns out that was correct, and now my GetEvents code is being called on the backend. Posting here in-case it helps someone else in the future.