# Populating fullcalendar with JSON from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, fullcalendar

I'm getting my data from ASP.NET MVC's controller using the following

```
      $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetHolidayLists", "Holiday")', null, function (result) {

          alert(JSON.stringify(result));  

          holidayList = result;

      });
```

This is what got alerted out:

```
[{"start":"/Date(1362139909000)/","title":"New Year's Day"},
{"start":"/Date(1364473601000)/","title":"Good Friday"},
{"start":"/Date(1376050863000)/","title":"National Day"},
{"start":"/Date(1387900800000)/","title":"Christmas Day"}]
```

And finally, this is how I bind the json to the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: holidayList
});
```

But nothing seems to be loaded onto the grid.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544010/jquery-full-calendar-not-showing-events. Your snippet works for me when I change the date format.

Comment: Yes that's true. It works fine when I change the date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have the same issue as Graham Charles in this post:

[FullCalendar won't bind to Json feed from ASP.NET MVC3 Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526890/fullcalendar-wont-bind-to-json-feed-from-asp-net-mvc3-action)

Comment: I'm not using jquery.validate